# Tableau Server hourly google analytics updates

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, tableau-api

I'm setting up a Dashboard on Tableau Server and with a data source extract from Google Analytics.

I need it to refresh hourly.

When publishing the data source I have selected Fixed start and incremental refresh, and i can see that the end date is hardcoded to yesterday and I can only schedule update once a day.

This means that my Dashboard will only have data for the previous day. Is this a known limitation? Is there a way to achieve hourly automated data refreshes?

I thought of three possible solutions:

1) Using command line data extract update, but I don't see any parameter that allows me to control date range, so the end date would always be hardcoded to yesterday (?)

2) Using Tableau API. But again, my extract will only refresh to latest day yesterday.

3) Setting up a separate process to download the data into a database and then connect to it with Tableau. Not sure if in this case I will be able to  incrementally update the extract or if I have to reload the entire extract all the time.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Data processing takes up to 24 hours for the free version of Google Analytics and up to 4 hours for Analytics 360, so hourly updates do not really make sense (you get either unreliable data or no data at all).

Comment: I know, but it would be good to have the option to refresh incrementally data source and get whatever is available every 4 hours. Tableau Server GA connection let's you get today's data if you select today as end date. It just does not allow it as an incremental refresh.

Comment: If you have Analytics 360 you might consider hooking it up to BigQuery with the streaming option, and then do your Dashboard with a custom query. We did that and shoved a meta refresh into the template, and that worked okay for an almost realtime dashboard (but comes with a little extra cost).

Comment: If I had Analytics 360 would it be possible to refresh incrementally every 3 hours from Google Big Query connection?

Comment: There is an option for streaming exports, which sends hit data to BigQuery almost continuously, so you look at data almost in realtime (it lags by a few minutes). However given the price of GA360 (some 100k per year) it certainly wouldn't be worth  to buy it just for a dashboard. And alas BQ does not connect to the free version.

Comment: Thanks Eike. So no workarounds found with Tableau GA connection, I'm left with option 3 of build backend process.